# How to add initial default value in Django's EmailField()

Tags: html, django, forms, email

I have the following django scheme:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name_param        = forms.CharField()
    email_param       = forms.EmailField()
    message_param     = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    recaptcha_param   = ReCaptchaField()
```

My question is:

[image]

I'd like to implement something like [**this**](http://codoncloud.com:3000/feedback).
Also we'd like to enable direct overwrite-as-we-type on the default value.

Comment: Those are different things. The "overwrite-as-we-type" thing there is a placeholder, but that is not a default value; if you don't type anything that data will not be submitted with the form.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: What's the `placeholder` for that?

Comment: I don't understand that question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a placeholder attribute to your email_param field. So your forms.py would be:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name_param        = forms.CharField()
    email_param       = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput({'placeholder': 'test@example.com'}))
    message_param     = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    recaptcha_param   = ReCaptchaField()
```

Comment: As it's an email field, it would be better to use [`EmailInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#emailinput) rather than `TextInput` as the widget.

Answer (score 1):

That's just HTML

```
<input type="email" placeholder="This is used to contact you..." name="email"/>
```

Comment: It's better to set the placeholder in the form, like in Oli's answer, rather than manually rendering the email field in the template.

Comment: I agree, I was just pointing out it is just a HTML attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Just notice that the

forms.EmailField()

does not take as argument a widget.

The way you could do that could be

models.EmailField(max_length=255,default='you default value or example@email.com')

That is more robust that the html solution, as give you the way to manage that on the Database